# Intent para abrir perfil de con la app de facebook mediante Page ID, Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, facebook-api

estoy tratando de abrir con un botón un perfil de facebook, pero he probado y siempre abre con el navegador y no con la app de facebook, alguien me puede ayudar por favor, así lo llevo en este momento.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.facebook);
    //FACEBOOK
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/uniagustiniana?ref=hl/");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
    try{
        startActivity(intent);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        finish();
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para esto se necesita el "Facebook page id" , que se obtiene de esta forma:

- Desde la página ir a "About"
- Ir a "More Info"
- Ahí se encontrara el "Facebook Page ID"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Para abrir la aplicación se realiza de esta forma:

```
 String facebookId = "fb://page/<Facebook Page ID>"; //*Los signos < y > no van!
 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(facebookId )));
```

Te recomiendo validar el caso en el cual no exista la aplicación instalada. En este caso abrirá la página web si no encuentra la aplicación instalada.:

```
String facebookId = "fb://page/<Facebook Page ID>";
String urlPage = "http://www.facebook.com/mypage";

     try {
          startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(facebookId )));
        } catch (Exception e) {
         Log.e(TAG, "Aplicación no instalada.");
         //Abre url de pagina.
         startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
        }
```

Comment: Me ha funcionado de esta manera, muchas gracias.

Comment: Excelente Alfredo, Saludos!

Comment: A mi me a dado trabajo darme cuenta con los <> no van solamente seria "fb://page/Facebook Page ID";

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag exactamente Bruno es como un "placeholder" indicador de que eso tiene que ser reemplazado, en este caso por el PageID

Comment: Para los nobatos como yo que encontramos estas respuestas muy buenas pero con algunos detalles como estes nos dan algunos dolores de cabeza

Answer (score 2):

Esto podría funcionar:

```
public static String FACEBOOK_URL = "https://www.facebook.com/YourPageName";
public static String FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID = "YourPageName";

//método que obtiene la verdadera URL
public String getFacebookPageURL(Context context) {
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        int versionCode = packageManager.getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0).versionCode;
        if (versionCode >= 3002850) { //versiones nuevas de facebook
            return "fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" + FACEBOOK_URL;
        } else { //versiones antiguas de fb
            return "fb://page/" + FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID;
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return FACEBOOK_URL; //normal web url
    }
}
```

El método devuelve la URL correcta de facebook tanto si tiene instalada la app como si no.

Después se lanza el Intent

```
Intent facebookIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String facebookUrl = getFacebookPageURL(this);
facebookIntent.setData(Uri.parse(facebookUrl));
startActivity(facebookIntent);
```

Espero que te sirva