# Como abrir una pagina de facebook desde su aplicación? Aplicación en android studio

Tags: android

Quiero entrar en la página dentro de la aplicación y este código solo me manda para compartir algo con esa pagina, soy esudiante:(.

```
public void onclic2(View view) {
    Intent intentocompartir=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intentocompartir.setType("text/plain");
    uriString="https://www.facebook.com/ArmyUSA";
    intentocompartir.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, uriString);
    intentocompartir.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");
    startActivity(intentocompartir);
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido Neo, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**,saludos!

Comment: Neo iba a agregar una respuesta pero veo que esto ya se pregunto, revisa la pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/68903/intent-para-abrir-perfil-de-con-la-app-de-facebook-android/68948#68948 si tienes dudas puedes realizarlo en esa pregunta y con gusto te ayudamos, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como se dice en la la pagina oficial de [Android](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send)

*"Cuando construyes un intento, debes especificar la acción que deseas que el intento "dispare". Android define varias acciones, incluida la ACTION_SEND que, como probablemente pueda adivinar, indica que la intención es enviar datos de una actividad a otra, incluso a través de los límites del proceso."*

Y lo que tu estas haciendo en tu codigo con ACTION_SEND es *enviar datos* más no lanzar una nueva actividad en la cuál se muestre una pagina, como tu lo quieres.

Para abrir una pagina de Facebook en tu aplicación, puedes hacerlo desde:

URL: para abrir la pagina en un navegador.

ID:  para abrir la pagina en la Aplicación de Facebook (en caso de estar instalada).

¿Que necesitas?

- Primero obtén la URL de la pagina que quieres mostrar, tan solo abre la pagina de facebook en un navegador y copia la url (la vas a usar en las dos opciones).
- Dirígete a la siguiente [pagina](https://es.piliapp.com/facebook/id/), donde de igual manera vas a necesitar la url de tu pagina para obtener tu ID de Facebook el cuál tendra un formato "410939029485361".

Bien pasemos a código, una vez teniendo tu URL y tu ID de Facebook, crea lo siguiente:

En tu XML:

```
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/vantis_facebook"
            android:text="@string/abrir_facebbok"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

en tu archivo JAVA:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private Button button;
    private String facebookId   ="fb://page/ID_DE_TU_PAGINA";
    private String facebookUrl  ="URL_DE_TU_PAGINA";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CargarRedesSociales(facebookId, facebookUrl);
            }
        });
    }
}

private void CargarRedesSociales(String urlId, String urlUrl) {
        try {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlId)));
        }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlUrl)));
        }
    }
```