# Cómo agregar Botón me gusta fan page en Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Estoy intentando poner un boton o imagen de facebook en mi aplicación y que me permita que al darle clic se me abra la app de facebook o la fans page. Sinceramente hasta ahora solo he podido crear la imagen con sus atributos porque busque info en internet y todas las formas que encontrè dicen que de versiones anteriores en android studio y al intentar usarlas me cierran la aplicación. Me podrán ayudar?

Comment: Aqui tienes una posible solucion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android en caso que te persista el error, seria preciso que añadieras mas información respecto al stack de error para que te podamos ayudar.

Comment: Hola Luis, trata de agregar código a tus preguntas o lo que hayas realizado, esto ya fue preguntado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/68903/intent-para-abrir-perfil-de-con-la-app-de-facebook-mediante-page-id-android